# Firestore Security Rules Regex

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to evaluate a `string` in **Firestore Security Rules** based on the [matches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) regex functionality

my code is `username.matches('^(?!\.)(?!_)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$')`

Using a regex simulator online it's working

https://regex101.com/r/bDXMg3/2/

But using the same syntax in Security Rules is throwing a ton of errors

[image]

I tried to then double escape each `.`

using the code `username.matches('^(?!\\.)(?!_)(?!.*\\.$)(?!.*?\\.\\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$')`

It only shows one error (red ^ sign at the beginning), but then it gives me the error below

[image]

```
Invalid regular expression pattern. Pattern: ^(?!\.)(?!_)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$.
```

My goal is to:

- Not start with a `.` or `_`
- Not end with a `.`
- Don't allow two `.` in a row
- Only lowercase `letter characters` and `numbers`

### Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is in the link below from [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

> If it is really RE2 that is parsing this pattern, then it is clear -
>   it does not support lookaheads/lookbehinds.

Use `'^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]*([.][a-z0-9_]+)*$'`

[Google RE2 Regex Escaping periods and underscores error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993680/google-re2-regex-escaping-periods-and-underscores-error?noredirect=1#comment90937243_51993680)