# Google RE2 Regex Escaping periods and underscores error

Tags: regex, re2

I'm trying to validate a `username` string with the following characteristics:

- Not start with a `.` or `_`
- Not end with a `.`
- Don't allow two `.` in a row
- Only lowercase `letter characters` and `numbers`

my code is `username.matches('^(?!\.)(?!_)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$')`

Using a regex simulator online it's working

https://regex101.com/r/bDXMg3/2/

But using the same syntax in **Google RE2 Syntax** (used in [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches)) is throwing a ton of errors

[image]

I tried to then double escape each `.`

using the code `username.matches('^(?!\\.)(?!_)(?!.*\\.$)(?!.*?\\.\\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$')`

It only shows one error (red ^ sign at the beginning), but then it gives me the error below

[image]

```
Invalid regular expression pattern. Pattern: ^(?!\.)(?!_)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9_.]+$.
```

### Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If it is really RE2 that is parsing this pattern, then it is clear - it does not support lookaheads/lookbehinds. Actually, you should use `/^[a-z0-9]+([_.][a-z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: Or, if I get the rules right, `'^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]*([.][a-z0-9_]+)*$'`

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work. If you add as a response to the original question I can mark as accepted answer

Comment: Posted with explanations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RE2  does not support lookaheads (nor lookbehinds).

However, the pattern can be re-written without lookarounds:

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]*([.][a-z0-9_]+)*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z0-9]` - a letter or digit
- `[a-z0-9_]*` - zero or more lowercase letters, digits, or underscores
- `([.][a-z0-9_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[.]` - a dot
  - `[a-z0-9_]+` - one or more lowercase letters, digits, or underscores
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, I adapted your expression to allow umlaute and the characters `.` , ` ` , `-` and `_` are only allowed between letters and numbers. However, I struggle with limiting the overall character length between 3 and 40 characters. Everthing works, except I don´t know where to put the char-limit.

`^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ0-9]+([. _-][a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ0-9]+)*$`

Comment: @LukyFoggy Sorry, with RE2 regex, it is impossible. Total string length limit is set with a lookahead, but RE2 does not support these constructs.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue. @WiktorStribiżew if I had to add a length to it like .{3,30}
I was thinking to use `(?=.{3,30}$)` ahead of `^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_]*([.][a-z0-9_]+)*$` but that not going to work. How do I do it?

Comment: @SubhenduKundu See my answer to [Github username convention using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726961/3832970)

Comment: I'm a novice an unsure, but consider a separate check using ```…size() > 3 && …size() < 40```