# Github username convention using regex

Tags: regex, go

I've been trying to convert the Github username convention using regex in Go for a while now and I couldn't do it. Also the username length **shouldn't exceed more than 39 characters**.

Below is the username convention from Github

> Username may only contain alphanumeric characters or single hyphens, and cannot begin or end with a hyphen.

and for the length

> Username is too long (maximum is 39 characters).

Here is the code I've written. You could check here in [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PTu76U_512w)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    usernameConvention := "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

    if re, _ := regexp.Compile(usernameConvention); !re.MatchString("abc-abc") {
        fmt.Println("false")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}
```

Currently, I could achieve these:

```
a-b // true - Working!
-ab // false - Working!
ab- // false - Working!
0-0 // true - Working!
```

But the problem I'm facing is that I couldn't find the regex pattern which should work for the below scenario:

```
a-b-c // false - Should be true
```

Also it has to be within 39 characters which I've found that we could use `{1,38}`, but I don't know where exactly should I add that in the regex pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2}$`fit here?

Comment: Why use a regex? This is easier, and more efficiently done, in other ways.

Comment: Not everything that can be validated by a regexp should be. Normal code is better for stuff like this.

Comment: In GO RE2-based regex, you can't use lookarounds, so checking length limit can only be done either with another regex, or with regular string length checking. See [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/EZU507Gnhr-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Go RE2-based regex, you can't use lookarounds, so checking length limit can only be done either with another regex, or with regular string length checking.

A fully non-regex approach ([demo](https://play.golang.org/p/4_MMSpv-dVU)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)
func IsAlnumOrHyphen(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if (r < 'a' || r > 'z') && (r < 'A' || r > 'Z') && (r < '0' || r > '9') && r != '-' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    s := "abc-abc-abc"
    if  len(s) < 40 && len(s) > 0 && !strings.HasPrefix(s, "-") && !strings.Contains(s, "--") && !strings.HasSuffix(s, "-") && IsAlnumOrHyphen(s) {
        fmt.Println("true")
    } else {

        fmt.Println("false")
    }
}
```

**Details**

- `len(s) < 40 && len(s) > 0` - Length restriction, from 1 to 39 chars are allowed
- `!strings.HasPrefix(s, "-")` - should not start with `-`
- `!strings.Contains(s, "--")` - should not contain `--`
- `!strings.HasSuffix(s, "-")` - should not end with `-`
- `IsAlnumOrHyphen(s)` -  can only contain ASCII alphanumeric and hyphens.

For a partially regex approach, see [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/eV6KrJ70IBD):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    usernameConvention := "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"
    re,_ := regexp.Compile(usernameConvention)
    s := "abc-abc-abc"
    if len(s) < 40 && len(s) > 0 && re.MatchString(s) {
        fmt.Println("true")
    } else {

        fmt.Println("false")
    }
}
```

Here, the `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `-` and then 1 or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.